Which phrase would a native speaker typically use to connect the supporting argument in paragraph 2 to the original viewpoint in paragraph 1?
Context: In an IELTS essay where I need to give my opinion on "whether the best way to solve the world’s environmental problems is to increase the cost of fuel".

(In the first paragraph, I argue that this is not the best way because traffic emissions only contribute to about 16% of the world's total greenhouse gas emissions.)

The second paragraph goes:

_______, I note the root cause of the most serious environmental issues: our energy-hungry lifestyles. For example,...Thus, the key to solving the world’s environmental problems is to find alternative sources of energy...

Now, setting aside the question of whether my essay is well-structured and my ideas are well-developed, let's focus on the main question:
I have two phrases, To strengthen my claim/argument VS To add further credence to my assertion, that I could use to fill in the blank. Which phrase would a native speaker use in academic writing to connect the supporting argument in the following paragraph to the original point of view in the previous paragraph? If you think neither of these phrases is natural or commonly used, please suggest an alternative.

You will probably get better and more helpful answers at https://ell.stackexchange.com/, our site for English language learners, or https://english.stackexchange.com/, our site for questions about the English language.

Actually, I asked this question on ell first and was advised to ask it here. Maybe there're no stack exchange sites which answers this kind of question?

Try and see what answers you get on English.SE, then.

No matter which Stack Exchange site you go to, asking which expression is better is inviting opinion and will result in the question being closed. You could heavily edit the post so it only asks one question (multiple questions in the one post are also grounds for closure), and modify the request so you're asking a question that can be answered by fact rather than opinion, but it's a lot of work. FWIW, both expressions are fine, but the 2nd is much more formal and a bit old-fashioned, more typical of an 1890s speech by Lord Belfrybat to the Royal Society.

Therefore,
Thus,
Consequentially,
In light of this,
Considering this,
[if you delete the phrase "I note" ...]
It follows [the root cause...]
This suggests [the root cause...]
EDIT to answer OP's comment:
You should not say "To strengthen my claim" before you have made a claim.
Likewise, you should not say "To add further credence to my assertion" before you have made an assertion.
Both of these would be fine for a native speaker, but in an academic paper (I've published several) you should be writing logically; and it isn't logical  to "strengthen" or "add credence to" something that doesn't exist yet.

to connect the supporting argument in the following paragraph to the original point of view in the previous paragraph?

The connection is implicit. If anything, I would use the word "further". Alternatives are "critically", "additionally", "finally", "Perhaps most importantly".

Further, I note the root cause of the most serious environmental issues: our energy-hungry lifestyles. For example,...

Although omitting "I" would be better; that suggests a personal opinion. If you are making a claim of fact, make it.

Perhaps most importantly, the root cause of the most serious environmental issues is our energy-hungry lifestyles. For example,...


Thank you, but it seems that you are suggesting some causal adverbial phrases, unlike what I'm asking for here.

Edited to reflect OP's comment.

It's an opinion essay, so "I" is okay.

Re strengthen my argument, I think my argument does exist in the first paragrpaph. It's the argument that increasing the cost of fuel is not the best solution. Could you please expand on your explanation?

@AnIELTSlearner Your conclusion: "Thus, the key to solving the world’s environmental problems is to find alternative sources of energy" is your claim. The proper order is "1: fuel is only 16% of the problem, thus raising fuel costs does not address 84% of the problem. 2: The major cause is lifestyle. 3: Because of XYZ this won't be affected by higher fuel costs. 4: The most impact will be had by finding alternative sources of energy." The conclusion is #4, not #3. #1 is an observation, and #3 is the evidence that follows from that observation, but #4 is the conclusion based on those elements.

Could the word you're looking for be something like 'rather' or 'instead'?
Like this:

Rather/instead, I note the root cause of the most serious
environmental issues: our energy-hungry lifestyles. For
example,...Thus, the key to solving the world’s environmental problems
is to find alternative sources of energy...

The function of this would be for you to move on to something that you find more crucial to the discussion - something which better answers the question/problem.

Thank you but the aim of pointing out the root cause is to support my argument in first paragraph that raising fuel cost is not the best solution because it doesn't address the root cause. So I feel that my two phrases are more suitable than "rather/instead". What do you think?

Your conclusion: "Thus, the key to solving the world’s environmental problems is to find alternative sources of energy" is your claim. The proper order is "1: fuel is only 16% of the problem, thus raising fuel costs does not address 84% of the problem. 2: The major cause is lifestyle. 3: Because of XYZ this won't be affected by higher fuel costs. 4: The most impact will be had by finding alternative sources of energy."  The conclusion is #4, not #3. #1 is an observation, and #3 is the evidence that follows from that observation, but #4 is the conclusion based on those elements.
